# How do I remove yellow discolouration from a scanned B&W photo in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, black-and-white, restoration

I have a b&w photo that seems to have been impacted by sunlight.  It’s not an overall yellow cast, but lots of imperfections.  I have photoshop, and although not an experienced user, I have some knowledge of the basics such as healing brush. I get a little lost on layers and stuff.  Could someone point me in the right direction of the best steps / YouTube videos etc to try and get back to b&w.   Ideally I’d like to print it again.  It’s my late father in the picture and it’s one of my favourites.image attached for reference.  Many thanks

[image]

Comment: It sounds simple, but you could try just scanning it as mono/ black & white, instead of colour?

Comment: Thanks Alastair, it would still have all the discoloured ‘damage’, around elbows, and hand it would just be a different colour.  I know I could sit and manually heal/replace which I will try, but it’s a lot to fix, and was just wondering if there are tricks in PS that work magic!

Answer (score 1):

If you select PhotoShop's  'Image -> Adjustments -> Black and White' menu you'll be able to get rid of the color information. You can also go to 'Image -> Mode -> Grayscale' and convert, although that gives you less control. Here's a quick pass with greyscale, a little contrast, and a little sharpening. You may want to do more to get rid of the various imperfections...

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob, I’ve looked so much at this image, that the obvious escaped me.  Seeing what you’ve done (and I know another person commented about scanning as b&w), should help with healing as the yellow colour is out of the way.  Will definitely try your suggestion, on getting rid of colour info.  I may just have to patiently work my way through healing the imperfections manually.